# Named query with composite key (EJB)

Tags: sql, hibernate, ejb, named-query

I have a associative table with composite key. I am trying to run a named query that selects based on some values (the composite key(s)).

This is what the code looks like:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "MW.findAll", query = "SELECT mw FROM MemberWorkout mw"),
@NamedQuery(name = "MW.find1", query = "SELECT mw FROM MemberWorkout mw WHERE mw.SocialSecurity LIKE :SocialSecurity"), })
@Table(name = "MemberWorkout")
public class MemberWorkout implements Serializable {

private Member member;
private Workout workout;
private String date;
private MWId mwId;

@EmbeddedId
public MWId getId() {
    return mwId;
}

public void setId(MWId mwId) {
    this.mwId = mwId;
}
....
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SocialSecurity", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Member getMember() {
    return member;
}

public void setMember(Member member) {
    this.member = member;
}
```

This is the first error that I get when I deploy this and start the server (JBOSS):

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000177:   Error in named query: MW.find1: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: SocialSecurity of: org.ics.ejb.MemberWorkout [SELECT mw FROM org.ics.ejb.MemberWorkout mw WHERE mw.SocialSecurity LIKE :SocialSecurity]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1809) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:313) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:485) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:598) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:266) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:213) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:118) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:883) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1246) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4252) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3874) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1923) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:782) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:583) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:974) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:485) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
```

Comment: Your entity does not seem to have a field named `SocialSecurity` or an approprate getter. The error is to be expected.

Comment: How can I have a field name SocialSecurity if that is part of a composite key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, the `SocialSecurity` is a field of the `MWId` embeddable. If you want to access it with a query, you will need to navigate to it through your embedded Id like this:

```
SELECT mw FROM MemberWorkout mw WHERE mw.id.SocialSecurity...
```

I am assuming that the property name is capitalized, as in your code. If not, replace it with the proper name.

Please note that you are using property access, meaning that because the accessor method is annotated, you need to name the property in your query according to the JavaBean standard (`getId()` means that HQL and JPQL will access the preperty as `id`). If you annotate the field, you will need to change the query to `mwId`.

Comment: Thanks alot! One of the many misstakes that I did was to try mw.getId... not knowing to leave out the 'get' and lowercase the first letter (ie. 'id'). Second I tried to access my property with the actual name of the table (in SQL) and not the property name.